# extract word from string with multiple delimeters

Tags: c#, linq, substring

this is my url:

https://videodb.blob.core.windows.net/video/0c7f5ecf-22fc-4032-8ca1-17481f18aaa8_twitter.jpg

Now i want to fetch **twitter** from my url in my query.

```
  var userDetails = context
      .UserDetails
      .Where(x => x.Email == _userDetails.Email && x.Password == _userDetails.Password)
      .Select(x => 
          new UserDetailsModel
          {
              Filename= x.Videourl
          });
```

in my file name i want just Name of file instead of whole url in my query only.

how to do this??

Comment: What is `context`? What is `_userDetails`? What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: do you want `0c7f5ecf-22fc-4032-8ca1-17481f18aaa8_twitter.jpg` ?

Comment: @Arshad:  i just want twitter

Comment: you can use ``System.IO`` namespace : ``System.IO.Path.GetFileName(x.Videourl)`` but if it is from DB then load resuts in memory first

Comment: @EhsanSajjad:yes it is from db

Comment: @Arshad `var fileName = "twitter"` then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try :

```
string url = "https://videodb.blob.core.windows.net/video/0c7f5ecf-22fc-4032-8ca1-17481f18aaa8_twitter.jpg";
string fileName = url.Substring(url.LastIndexOf('_') + 1);
```

This will return you  `twitter.jpg`

If you need file name without extension:

```
string fileNameWithoutExtention = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName);
```

It will give you `twitter`.

Comment: Why not `var fileName = "twitter.jpg"` then?! If the OP wants twitter, give 'em twitter :)

Comment: but what is if name is like this:0c7f5ecf-22fc-4032-8ca1-17481_f18aaa8_twitter.jpg

Comment: `var` will be string only.

Comment: @Mihai:but thats the whole url is coming not simply name is coming

Comment: this will also work, because I am taking last index of _

Comment: to complete the answer, after above code, use `String`'s `Split()` method with parameter as `_`. After that reject first part & take "twitter.jpg". Split again with `.`. You will get "twitter".

Comment: @MangeshGhotage, This will not work if file name is `abc.def.jpg` or `twitter.V2.jpg`

Comment: @Arshad: Yes. Your logic is more robust.

Comment: i would like to thank u all for helping me.thank u once again guys and yaa please please please keep helping like this....

Answer (score 0):

Besides what Arshad did, you can also do this.

```
string url = "https://videodb.blob.core.windows.net/video/0c7f5ecf-22fc-4032-8ca1-17481f18aaa8_twitter.jpg";
string[] delimitedString = url.Split('_');
string fileName = delimitedString[delimitedString.Length - 1].Split('.')[0];
```